# Area of rectangle bounded by $u=0,~ u=a,~ v=0, ~v=1$ on helicoid defined by $x = u\cos v, ~ y=u\sin v, ~ z = av$.

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, 3d

> Find the area of rectangle bounded by $u=0,~ u=a,~ v=0, ~v=1$ on helicoid defined by $x = u\cos v, ~ y=u\sin v, ~ z = av$.

I have solved many problems of similar kind in my calculus course, but this problem is from differential geometry book which I'm self-studying. I don't have any algorithm in my mind. I can't imagine the graph too. Maybe some kind of variable-change to flatten the surface.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with surface integrals?

Comment: @user170231 Yes I am, but not very comfortable with them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A surface $S$ parameterized by a vector-valued function $\vec r(u,v)$ has area equal to the [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral)

$$\iint_S\mathrm dA=\int_0^1\int_0^a\left\|\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}\right\|\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

You're generously provided with the parameterization and domain of integration. Differentiating $\vec r(u,v)$ gives

$$\vec r(u,v)=\left\langle u\cos v,u\sin v,av\right\rangle\implies\begin{cases}\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}=\left\langle\cos v,\sin v,0\right\rangle\\\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}=\left\langle-u\sin v,u\cos v,a\right\rangle\end{cases}$$

Find the normal vector to $S$, which is the cross product of these partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}=\left\langle a\sin v,-a\cos v,u\right\rangle$$

Compute its norm:

$$\left\|\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}\right\|=\sqrt{(a\sin v)^2+(-a\cos v)^2+u^2}=\sqrt{a^2+u^2}$$

You can think of this norm factor as an extension of the Jacobian determinant you typically use for integrating over a plane. Roughly speaking, it essentially scales up an area over a flat plane to compensate for the curvature of the surface. (I think the linked Wikipedia article does a decent job of explaining this more rigorously, and in fact that's where I first picked up the concept!)

So the area would be

$$\int_0^1\int_0^a\sqrt{a^2+u^2}\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=\int_0^a\sqrt{a^2+u^2}\,\mathrm du$$

and the remaining integral is elementary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the beginner-friendly explanation! So if I'm asked to find the area of some shape $S$ along some surface $\vec r(u,v)$ I use this fact, right? In my example $S$ is the rectangle and $\vec r$ is the helicoid. Is $\mathrm dA$ just $\mathrm du \mathrm dv$?

Comment: (1) Not quite, both $S$ and $\vec r$ represent the same rectangular subset of the overall helicoid, but it's $\vec r$ that *defines* $S$. In other words, every point on $S$ can be obtained by plugging in various $u$ and $v$ within the given domain. (2) No, $\mathrm dA=\color{red}{\|\text{normal vector}\|}\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$.

Comment: Exactly. You're looking for the area of a rectangular subset of the helicoid.

Comment: @user170231 Perfect, I hope I got it all because of your help. Thank you.

Comment: @NodeJS: I don't know what differential geometry text you're studying, but you might look at mine. Freely downloadable, the link in my profile. For this particular matter, look at section 1 of chapter 2 (and this particular formula is derived in a careful fashion on p. 40-41).